# elasticsearch query scripting with variables

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I need to update a lot of documents already inserted on elasticsearch 5.4.
I think I'm missing some BIG concept here, because I need to do something simply and I can't.

I need to cut the 6 last numbers of "req.body.client.id" and hide the rest (replacing by x).
Example: 9494402234028493247 ---> xxxxxxxxxxxxxx493247

I could do it! But the problem is that the code is soo long. I would like to use a VARIABLE and I can't. I don't want to REPEAT the field ctx._source.req.body.client.id 4 times. It would be better if I could do that:
clientId = ctx._source.req.body.client.id and then use clientId in the rest of the script line.
What is the right way to do that?

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "req.body.client.id":"94944022.*"
        }
    },
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "inline": "ctx._source.req.body.client.id = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' + ctx._source.req.body.client.id.substring(ctx._source.req.body.client.id.length()-6,ctx._source.req.body.client.id.length())"
    }
 }
```

The question is about VARIABLES and code simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It's a language called PAINLESS. The right way is:

```
"String clientId = ctx._source.req.body.client.id; 
int cLen = clientId.length(); 
ctx._source.req.body.client.id = "xxxxxxxxxxx" + clientId.substring(cLen-4,cLen);"
```